# Grab certain rows from main array to insert into another array to copy into a target sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I have a big spreadsheet I parse into other spreadsheets. I have something working, albeit slowly.

I read that using arrays is a better approach.

How do I grab certain rows from the main array and insert them into another array to copy into a target sheet at the end?

Here are the original, working functions:

```vb
Private Function CopyValues(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range)
    rngTarget.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
End Function
    
Private Function RESORT(FROMSHEET As Variant, Column As Variant, TOSHEET As Variant, EXTRA1 As Variant, EXTRA2 As Variant, EXTRA3 As Variant)
    Set i = Sheets(FROMSHEET)
    Set e = Sheets(TOSHEET)
    
    Dim d
    Dim j
    Dim q
    d = 1
    j = 2
    
    e.Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Clear
    i.Select
    Rows(1).Copy
    e.Select
    Rows(1).PasteSpecial
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("G" & j))
        If i.Range(Column & j) = "Total" Then
            i.Select
            Rows(j).Copy
            e.Select
            Rows(2).PasteSpecial
            ' CopyValues i.Rows(j), e.Rows(2)
            Exit Do
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    
    d = 2
    j = 2
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("G" & j))
        
        If i.Range(Column & j) = TOSHEET Or i.Range(Column & j) = EXTRA1 Or i.Range(Column & j) = EXTRA2 Or i.Range(Column & j) = EXTRA3 Then
            d = d + 1
            CopyValues i.Range(i.Cells(j, 1), i.Cells(j, 11)), e.Range(e.Cells(d, 1), e.Cells(d, 11)) 'e.Range("A" & d)
            
        ElseIf i.Range("A" & j) = e.Range("A" & d) And i.Range("I" & j) = "Total" Then
            d = d + 1
            e.Select
            Rows(2).Copy
            Rows(d).PasteSpecial
            ' CopyValues e.Rows(2), e.Rows(d)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    e.Select
    Rows(2).Delete
    Range("A1").Select
    
End Function
```

Here's what I'm hacking on, many different attempts in there:

```vb
Private Function RESORT2(FROMSHEET As Variant, Column As Variant, TOSHEET As Variant, EXTRA1 As Variant, EXTRA2 As Variant, EXTRA3 As Variant)
    ' Set i = Sheets(FROMSHEET)
    ' Set e = Sheets(TOSHEET)
    Dim d
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    Dim myarray As Variant
    Dim arrTO As Variant
    
    d = 1
    j = 1
          
    'myarray = Worksheets(FROMSHEET).Range("a1").Resize(10, 20)
    myarray = Worksheets(FROMSHEET).Range("a1:z220").Value 'Resize(10, 20)
    For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
        If myarray(i, 9) = TOSHEET Then
            'arrTO = myarray
            '  Worksheets(TOSHEET).Range("A" & j).Resize(1, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray(i))
            Worksheets(TOSHEET).Range("A" & j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)
            '   arrTO = j 'Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(myarray, 0, 1)

            j = j + 1
                
        End If
            
    Next
    Worksheets(TOSHEET).Range("a1").Resize(10, 20) = arrTO
    
End Function
```

**First Edit**
I tried cleaning up:

```vb
Private Function RESORT(FROMSHEET As Variant, Column As Variant, TOSHEET As Variant, EXTRA1 As Variant, EXTRA2 As Variant, EXTRA3 As Variant)
    Set FRO = Sheets(FROMSHEET)
    Set TOO = Sheets(TOSHEET)
    
    Dim TOO_IND
    Dim FRO_IND
    Dim TotalRow
    
    TotalRow = 2
    TOO_IND = 2
    FRO_IND = 2
    
    TOO.Cells.Clear
    TOO.Rows(1).Value = FRO.Rows(1).Value
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(FRO.Range("G" & TotalRow))
        If FRO.Range(Column & TotalRow) = "Total" Then
            FRO.Select
            Rows(TotalRow).Copy
            TOO.Select
            Rows(2).PasteSpecial
            ' CopyValues FRO.Rows(j), TOO.Rows(2)
            Exit Do
        End If
        TotalRow = TotalRow + 1
    Loop
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(FRO.Range("G" & FRO_IND))
        
        If FRO.Range(Column & FRO_IND) = TOSHEET Or FRO.Range(Column & FRO_IND) = EXTRA1 Or FRO.Range(Column & FRO_IND) = EXTRA2 Or FRO.Range(Column & FRO_IND) = EXTRA3 Then
            TOO_IND = TOO_IND + 1
            TOO.Rows(TOO_IND).Value = FRO.Rows(FRO_IND).Value
        ElseIf FRO.Range("A" & FRO_IND) = TOO.Range("A" & TOO_IND) And FRO.Range("I" & FRO_IND) = "Total" Then
            TOO_IND = TOO_IND + 1
            TOO.Select
            Rows(2).Copy
            Rows(TOO_IND).PasteSpecial
         '   TOO.Rows(TOO_IND).PasteSpecial = FRO.Rows(2).PasteSpecial  ' this isn't working, I need format and formula, if I just do .formula it doesn't work
        End If
        FRO_IND = FRO_IND + 1
    Loop
    
    TOO.Rows(2).Delete
    'Range("A1").Select
    
End Function
```

It's slower (3.2s vs. 2.86s on my smallest sample set).

I think the array is going to be the solution. I run this routine multiple times on the same sample set, but with different qualifiers, if in the main I dump the sample set into an array, then pass this array to this sort routine, I think it'll be faster. I'm still do not know how to do my operations on arrays, specifically copying one row from array to array.

**Second Edit**
I'm much closer now! What once took ~133 seconds, now only takes 10.51 seconds!

I'm still trying to trim up some time. I have not yet coded anything to grab the array once and then pass the array to the RESORT function, I'm looking into that next to see if that will help speed things up.

Is there a way to copy the formula and the value into the same array?  I don't like the way I do it, but it does work.

```vb
Private Function RESORT(FROMSHEET As Variant, Column As Variant, TOSHEET As Variant, EXTRA1 As Variant, EXTRA2 As Variant, EXTRA3 As Variant)
    Set FRO = Sheets(FROMSHEET)
    Set TOO = Sheets(TOSHEET)
    
    Dim TotalRow
    
    TotalRow = 2
    TOO_IND = 2
    FRO_IND = 2
    
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim FROM_Row As Long
    Dim TO_Row As Long
    
    Const NumCol = 25
    
    Dim myarray As Variant
    Dim myarrayform As Variant
    Dim arrTO(1 To 1000, 1 To 2000)
    Dim arrTotal(1 To 1, 1 To NumCol)
    
    TO_Row = 2
    myarray = Worksheets(FROMSHEET).Range("a1:z1000").Value
    myarrayform = Worksheets(FROMSHEET).Range("a1:z1000").FormulaR1C1
    
    TOO.Cells.Clear
    
    For Col = 1 To NumCol
        arrTO(1, Col) = myarray(1, Col)
    Next
    
    For FROM_Row = 1 To UBound(myarray)
        If myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = "Total" Then
            For Col = 1 To NumCol
                arrTotal(1, Col) = myarrayform(FROM_Row, Col)
            Next
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    For FROM_Row = 1 To UBound(myarray)
        If myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = TOSHEET Or myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = EXTRA1 Or myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = EXTRA2 Or myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = EXTRA3 Then
            For Col = 1 To NumCol
                arrTO(TO_Row, Col) = myarray(FROM_Row, Col)
            Next
            TO_Row = TO_Row + 1
        ElseIf myarray(FROM_Row, 1) = arrTO(TO_Row - 1, 1) And myarray(FROM_Row, Column) = "Total" Then
            For Col = 1 To NumCol
                arrTO(TO_Row, Col) = arrTotal(1, Col)
            Next
            TO_Row = TO_Row + 1
        End If
    Next
    Worksheets(TOSHEET).Range("a1").Resize(1000, 2000) = arrTO
    
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see any collections in your code other than built in VBA collections. What collections are you using?

Comment: When you do `PasteSpecial` with no parameters, are you trying to just transfer values?

Comment: I'm not sure what "collections" are, can you help me with that?  When I use the PasteSpecial in those two locations it's to retain the formula and format of those rows.  My attempt at the time was to only copy values to save time as much as I could (I think it did help some).

Comment: Do you have a sample file you could post - I'd be happy to take a look if I don't need to recreate an example.

Comment: brettdj, I'll look into this, it has alot of personal financial information, I'll think about how to sanitize it.

Answer (score 4):

Iterating over arrays in VBA will not necessarily be faster than iterating over the collection objects that your first method uses.  The collections are likely implemented as linked lists, so for the purpose of starting at the beginning and looping over them, they will be equally as speedy as arrays.

The high-level answer is that your sort algorithm will *usually* be vastly more important than your specific code details.  That is, as long as your details don't somehow increase the complexity of running that algorithm.

In my experience, the best way to speed up VBA is to eschew all functions that have an effect on the UI.  If your code moves around the selected cell, or switches the actively viewed sheet, etc, that is the biggest timesink.  I think those functions `Select`, `Copy()`, and `PasteSpecial()` might be guilty of that.  It would be better to store worksheet and range objects, and write directly to their cells as required.  You do that in your 2nd method, and I think it is much more important than changing your data type.

Comment: Seth, thanks for taking time to help me with this, I see where you're going with this, I'll try eliminating some of those functions you mention and I'll see if they cut my time down.  I'll edit my main post with my findings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Seth Battin, but have a few additional things to add.

While arrays can be faster, if you need to search them they do not scale well. The code you have written will iterate through your dataset n times (where n is the number of `TOSHEET`s you have). Also your code is writing data to the worksheet once for each row (which is time consuming), It is faster (but more code) to put all the data into a single 2D array and write once.

A better program flow might be

Read each line of data

Assign it to a data structure (I would use a scripting dictionary containing 2D arrays)

After all the data is read iterate the scripting dictionary outputting each 2D array

This will minimize both reads and writes to the spreadsheet which is where the preformance bottlenecks are for this type of vba program.

Comment: Pynner, Thanks for the comment, I appreciate your time.  Those tips are exactly the code I don't know how to write yet, can you point me in the right direction with examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would definitely speed up your code by using arrays instead of collections of cells. This is because accessing the properties of the objects takes time.

Honestly though, your code would likely not benefit very much from using arrays as your code is more reasonably modified by eliminating unnecessary loops.

I've re-written the beginning of your RESORT function in a more Excel centric way avoiding some of the pitfalls like selects. I'd also suggest trying to use variable names that are meaningful, especially for objects.

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
Private Function RESORT(FROMSHEET As Variant, Column As Variant, TOSHEET As Variant, EXTRA1 As Variant, EXTRA2 As Variant, EXTRA3 As Variant)
'Actually indicate variable types.
dim i as worksheet, dim e as worksheet
dim searchRange as Range

Set i = Sheets(FROMSHEET)
Set e = Sheets(TOSHEET)


Dim d as long
Dim j as long
dim lastRow as long 'Using a meaningful variable name
d = 1
j = 2

'I'm assuming you were using PasteSpecial because you only want values.
'I removed your unnecessary selects
e.Cells.Clear
'Move values directly instead of copy paste
i.Rows(1).value = e.Rows(1).value

'Check the first range
If Not IsEmpty(.Range("G" & j)) Then
    'Determine the last row to check.
    'This would break if j is equivalent to the last possible row... 
    'but only an example
    If IsEmpty(.Range("G" & j+1) then
        lastRow = j
    else 
        lastrow = i.Range("G" & j).End(xlDown).Row
    end if
    'Get the search Range
    'We might have used arrays here but it's less complicated to 
    ' use built in functions.
    Set searchRange = i.Range(i.Range(Column & j), _
                      i.Range(Column, lastrow).Find("Total"))
    If Not (searchRange Is Nothing) Then
        'Copy the values of the found row.
        e.Rows(2).value = searchRange.EntireRow.value
    End If
End If
```

After doing that I realize that the part that might more reasonably use arrays is after where I stopped. If you want to use arrays here, what you need to do is effectively copy all of the relevant area to an array and then reference the array the same way that you would reference cells.

For Example:

```
myArray = i.Range("A1:B10")
MsgBox myArray(10, 2) 'Displays value of B10 (10th row, 2nd column)
MsgBox i.Cells(10, 2) 'Displays value of B10 (10th row, 2nd column)
```

Comment: Daniel, Thank you for taking time to help me with this, I'm in the process of trying out your ideas, slowly :D  I'll edit my main post if I find anything out.